# BeautifulSoup4 find multiple href's links with specific text in links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying filter all href links with the string "3080" in it, I saw some examples, but I just can't apply them to my code. Can someone tell me how to print only the links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import driver_functions

gpu = '3080'
url = f'https://www.alternate.de/listing.xhtml?q={gpu}'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service('chromedriver.exe'))
    try:

        browser.get(url)

        time.sleep(2)

        html = browser.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        gpu_list = soup.select("a", class_="grid-container listing")

        for link in gpu_list:
            print(link['href'])

        browser.quit()
    except:
        driver_functions.browserstatus(browser)
```

[Output](https://pastebin.com/RAt2VEAi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a css attribute = value css selector with * contains operator to target `href`s, within the listings, that contain that `gpu` variable. You can obviously develop this css selector list if you find edge cases to account for. I only looked at the url given.

```
gpu_links= [i['href'] for i in soup.select(f".listing [href*='{gpu}']")]
```

Comment: yes it worked thanks, but what does the "f listing" mean

Comment: and i dont understand what i['href'] means

Comment: `i` is the current item within the list comprehension. Like `for i in some_list`. `i['href']` is the way to access the `href` attribute. `f` is for f-string

Comment: f-string https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings

Comment: ahh okay thank you for the explanation, and one more question why does "listing" work when the class name is "grid-container listing"

Comment: It is a multi-valued class i.e. `grid-container` and  `listing`. You can refer to either or both `.grid-container.listing`. Bit of a judgement call based on experience  but I tend to go with a single, stable looking class, from multi-value, in order to do some measure of future proofing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your selector `gpu_list = soup.select('#lazyListingContainer > div > div > div.grid-container.listing > a')`

Comment: this solution doesnt seem very consistent or what does this > div >div mean ?